# Solar Celiac Plexus location in body

Tags: human-biology, physiology, human-anatomy

Where is the Solar (Celiac) Plexus located in relation to the ribcage? I am reading this on the internet, and trying to learn more.

"The solar plexus — also called the celiac plexus — is a complex system of radiating nerves and ganglia. It's found in the pit of the stomach in front of the aorta."

Can someone point it out in the picture below? The purple and blue areas in the picture is the ribcage.

[image]

Comment: Since this diagram contains only bones and muscle (diaphragm), you should not expect to find other things on it, like nerves and ganglia.

Comment: hi @BryanKrause I am asking about solarplexus location spacial relationship to the rib cage,

Comment: Honestly, the Wikipedia article tells you what you need to know here.  It gives a decent illustration (courtesy of Gray's) that shows how these nerves radiate "like rays of the sun" from a spot a little below the diaphragm.  The tougher part is understanding how splanchnic nerves of the sympathetic nervous system work with the vagus nerve of the parasympathetic, etc.  Use a [free textbook](https://openstax.org/details/books/anatomy-and-physiology) and start from the basics of the autonomic nervous system (Chapter 15); you'd never believe such a Rube Goldberg mechanism actually evolved!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the center of your figure. The yellowish downward pointing arrowhead is where it is, possible represented by the arrowhead. Immediately below the ribs/sturnum